# Exceptions Thrown by Await#result

Tags: scala, future, spray

Given the following code:

```
import spray.http._
import spray.client.pipelining._
import scala.concurrent.Future

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
import system.dispatcher // execution context for futures

val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive

val response: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Get("http://spray.io/"))
```

The following pseudo-code function waits 10 seconds, returning "GOOD" if the `HttpResponse` returned, or "BAD" on an `Await#result` exception (see [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$).

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def f(fut: Future[HttpResponse]): String = {
  try { 
    val result = Await.result(fut, 10.seconds)
    "GOOD"
  }
  catch e @ (_: InterruptedException | _: IllegalArgumentException 
       | _: TimeoutException ) => "BAD"
}
```

In my `catch`, is it only necessary to catch exception thrown by `Await#result`? In other words, am I not catching any possible exceptions here?

Comment: Whatever might be contained in a failed `Future`.. depends on the API.

Comment: `recover` would be more idiomatic than throwing and then catching.

Comment: Well, if I've passed in a `fut` that won't throw an Exception, then calling `recover` is unnecessary, no, @TravisBrown? I should've noted that I'm presuming `fut: Future[HttpResponse]` does not throw exceptions when evaluated.

Comment: In the event that `fut` is a total function, i.e. it throws no exceptions, then is it proper to still use `Future#recover` even though it's not necessary?

Answer (score 6):

The `Await.result` itself can throw the exceptions you caught, however, if the future it awaits does not complete successfully, it forwards the exception contained by the future.  You might want to read the Blocking section from here: [Futures and Promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking).

So yes, there may be exceptions you aren't catching, anything that can result from the failed computation of a `HttpResponse`.

Blocking in real code is usually bad and should be done only for testing purposes, but if you really need to, I would recommend to wrap the Await in a `scala.util.Try` so you could manipulate it elegantly later and also keep the information of when and why it failed.